# C# Reverse UrlPathEncode

Tags: c#, url

I have this:

> file://localhost/Volumes/Untitled%20RAID%20Set%201/Callum/iTunes/Music/Steppenwolf/Steppenwolf_%20Gold/1-09%20Magic%20Carpet%20Ride.mp3

It is a location on Mac, its path has been encoded for use in an XML file.

To make this path you can use UrlPathEncode.

But now, I want to put that back to its normal readable path i.e. minus %20 and other characters that are replaced such as acute "e" etc etc etc. Bar the "/" that can easily be changed to "\"

How can you do it with out writing your own "reverser"?

If it comes down to it I will, but I would rather not.

Comment: [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx)?

Comment: thing is, i kept typing it into google, and nothing...

Comment: Sorry, maybe the link-text wasn't clear; I posted a link to the MSDN page on the `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` method (which was also posted in DGibbs answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the opposite of `Encode` which is of course, `Decode`.. [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx):

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("file://localhost/Volumes/Untitled%20RAID%20Set%201/Callum/iTunes/Music/Steppenwolf/Steppenwolf_%20Gold/1-09%20Magic%20Carpet%20Ride.mp3");
```

Which will return:

```
file://localhost/Volumes/Untitled RAID Set 1/Callum/iTunes/Music/Steppenwolf/Steppenwolf_ Gold/1-09 Magic Carpet Ride.mp3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: [`Uri.UnescapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring.aspx)

```
Uri.UnescapeDataString("file://localhost/Volumes/Untitled%20RAID%20Set%201/Callum/iTunes/Music/Steppenwolf/Steppenwolf_%20Gold/1-09%20Magic%20Carpet%20Ride.mp3");
```

Output:

```
file://localhost/Volumes/Untitled RAID Set 1/Callum/iTunes/Music/Steppenwolf/Steppenwolf_ Gold/1-09 Magic Carpet Ride.mp3
```

May be helpful if you do not have access to `HttpUtility` (e.g using `.NET Framework Client Profile`)